# WindowService fails to write in a txt file when I run it from PCs different from mine (where I developed it)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, udp, windows-services, wifi

I made a very simple WindowsService that waits data from an UDP port trough WiFi and once received them, it writes them in a txt file (as many examples/tutorials that you can find on the web). I anticipate I usually develop WIndowsForm. The Service choise arises from the need to have a background process that always works, without showing anything to the user... the latter will check the file with the data saved only when needed.
Through the AppConfig.xml file a set the log path and file name and when I run it through VisualStudio no problems appear, as well when I install it (through prompt cmd) on my PC (where I developed it). Everything seems to work properly!
When I tried to install and run it on others PC (included the one where it's supposed to work), the WindowsService has been correctly installed and looked like to work but actually doesn't write on the file (first strange behaviour).
I think is something related to permission.
The account set in the installer is the LocalSystem.

[image: See attacched pic]

I tried to compile again my project but with the log path hard coded and equals to the directory where the WindowsService.exe is placed but it works only when I run it from VS. When I run it from Services it has the same behaviour seen before: it starts without any error but it doesn't write to the file (second strange behaviour). Obv it doesn't work also to the other PC.
In both cases (write or not) the output in the Process Monitor is the same.[Fail to write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiDYf.png) and [OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85tZU.png)
Finally, everytime I modify my code and I run it through VS, my Avast antivirus initially blocks the debug because it has to check the .exe file first. Then, the process starts correctly. It's like this only the first time after a change in the code (and so a change in the .exe). This doesn't happen, for example, when I develop and execute WindowsForm...
I'm blocked here from weeks, I hope so much in your help!
Many thanks in advance fot your time.
SB

Code below.
I search for a string in the text file (workbench station).
If this string is already present, I update its associated counter value.
If this string is not present, I added a new line with the new workbench and its counter value.

```
// Save data received in text file
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(docPath, fileName)))
{
    lineToFind = bancoDiLavoro.Insert(bancoDiLavoro.Length, receiveBytes[0].ToString());
    Console.Write("Line to find in text file: ");
    Console.WriteLine(lineToFind);
    allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(docPath, fileName));
    lineNumber = 0;

    while (allLines.Length != 0)
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;

        try
        {
            if (line != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(lineToFind))
                {
                    sr.Close();
                    lineFound = true;
                    allLines[lineNumber - 1] = lineToFind.Insert(lineToFind.Length, "\tConteggio: " + count.ToString() + "\t");
                    File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(docPath, fileName), allLines);
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Empty line found.");
                lineFound = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            lineFound = false;
        }
    }

    if (lineFound == false)
    {
        // Workbench not found: a new workstation has been added
        sr.Close();
        
        File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(docPath, fileName), lineToFind);
        File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(docPath, fileName), "\tConteggio: ");
        File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(docPath, fileName), count.ToString() + "\n");
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

[UPDATE]
I've been able to add the EventLog to my service and on the PCs where the service doesn't work, seem that the data are not received on UDP port (even if the port is correctly "opened"). I have to work on this now...
The service remains blocked here:
Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

```
try
        {
            //Creates a UdpClient for reading incoming data.
            UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(UDPport);

            //Creates an IPEndPoint to record the IP Address and port number of the sender.
            // The IPEndPoint will allow you to read datagrams sent from any source.
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            eventLog1.WriteEntry("UDP port opened.");

            while (waitForPacket == true)
            {
                // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
                Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

                Console.Write("Workbench: ");
                Console.Write(receiveBytes[0]);
                Console.Write(", count: ");
                Console.WriteLine(receiveBytes[1]);
                Console.WriteLine("This message was sent from " +
                                            RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() +
                                            " on their port number " +
                                            RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString());

                eventLog1.WriteEntry("data received.");
                // Continues with the data writing...
```

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing any code

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment and read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a good question, and also take a moment to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well, where you can learn how to provide a minimal reproducible example. Kind Regards!

Comment: Thanks. I added some code. My file is a list of indexes (representing workbench stations) and a counter values associated to them. Every workbench has its own counter. If new data come, I replace the old line (with the old counter value) with a new one.

Comment: Please check whether the generated configuration file XXXX.exe.config is copied to the directory where the service file is located. At this time, you need to copy the configuration file to the same directory as the service execution file, or the directory where the service file specifies the configuration file

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT thanks for your kindly answer. I don't think is something related to the config file since it's correctly placed in the same folder where the WindowService.exe file is placed too. In addition, notepad seems to correctly open the correct txt file (please see process monitor pic attached). I thought it was sufficient to set the service as Local system to have all the necessary accesses...

Comment: @Simon Hi, did you solve your issue after setting up the service as local system and have all the necessary access rights? Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Comment: Hi @wenbingeng-MSFT, nope.. the service has been set as Local system by the beginning of the project. Is there a way to verify if I have the necessary rights (and in case how to add them?).

Comment: @Simon Can you find some error messages in the syslog?

Comment: UPDATE: I've been able to add EventLog to my Service and, as previously said, on my PC everything works correctly (data reception and transcript). On the other PC seems that data are not received on UDP port! The service is blocked waiting for data... (I updated the question)

Comment: @Simon I noticed that the code you shared is not very comprehensive, but there is generally no problem. Usually we can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive?view=net-7.0 to get the data on the udp port. You can try to share more code. If you are sure the code you are using is ok. Then it should be that you have a firewall turned on on another computer and you need to turn it off.

Comment: [UPDATE] It works! I had to create a new rule to accept data from the specified UDP port! Now it works on both my PCs... next steps are first to edit the firewall rule to make it more safty (I have to read some documentation since I don't have any kind of experience about it) and then try all on the PC where the system is supposed to work (but now I think i will solve in the same way). Thanks a lot guys :)